# Load image and text in one UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uiimage

HI guys. I need to load image and text in UIWebView, I loaded image like that

```
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
    [myWebView loadData:imageData MIMEType:@"application/jpg" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

and text like that

```
[myWebView loadHTMLString:self.text baseURL:nil];
```

But when I put it together I see just image, because it is the last in code.
How can I load both (image and text) to one UIWebView? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create html-page dynamically and load it into UIWebView:

```
NSString *imageUrlString = @"http://www.gstatic.com/translate/intl/ru/logo.png";
NSString *yourText = @"Some text here";

NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src='%@'/><br><b>%@</b>", imageUrlString, yourText];    
[myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: can you please help me in how to Put icon inside input element . . .

Comment: @NamanVaishnav could you please show me a picture of what you want to get?

Comment: sir, please see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42382817/4125508