# Load image/logo in existing HTML input field - UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

as I'm new to programming I've done something like this :

```
- (void)completeUserFieldsForWebView:(UIWebView *)webView withUsername:(NSString *)username {

// TextField Which has Value "email"
NSString *loadUsernameJS =
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[type='email']\"); \
 for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { inputFields[i].value = '%@';}", username];

// TextField Which has Value "Text" if email is not found
NSString *loadText =
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[type='text']\"); \
 for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { inputFields[i].value = '%@';}", username];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: loadUsernameJS];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: loadText];
}
```

Which fill all the text fields according to my input . . .

```
- (void)completePasswordFieldsForWebView:(UIWebView *)webView withPassword:(NSString *)password {

NSString *loadPasswordJS =
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"var passFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[type='password']\"); \
 for (var i = passFields.length>>> 0; i--;) { passFields[i].value ='%@';}", password];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: loadPasswordJS];
}
```

which fills Password parameter in the certain HTML page in the UIWebView . . .

The question is how can I inject my own images in particular textbox ?

Try No. 1 :

```
  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var script = document.createElement('script');"
         "script.type = 'text/javascript';"
         "script.text = \"function myFunction() { "
         "var field = document.getElementById('txtAdminPwd');"
         "field.style.backgroundImage='url(icon1.png)';"
         "}\";"
         "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"];

        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunction();"];
```

Not getting Success . . .

Try No. 2(@arun's):

```
 NSString *cssString = @".login-text-box-bg1{  background-image:url(myProjectName/Arun.png); background-position: right top; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; }"; // 1
         NSString *javascriptString = @"var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '%@'; document.head.appendChild(style)"; // 2
        NSString *javascriptWithCSSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:javascriptString, cssString]; // 3
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptWithCSSString]; // 4
```

- local image is outside on my project . . .

Sir, Thanks for the effort but it's Still not solving the Universal Approach. . .

**New Test** : 
i can get id or class name via [inputNode getAttributeNamed:@"id"] [method][2](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser)

Now, what if I do something like this

```
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var script = document.createElement('script');"
         "script.type = 'text/javascript';"
         "script.text = \"function myFunction() { "
         "var field = document.getElementById('%@');"
         "field.style.backgroundImage = 'url('icon1.png')';"

         "}\";"
         "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);",[inputNode getAttributeNamed:@"id"]];

        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunction();"];
```

but it's throwing an error can't we pass an argument ?? leave:\

My Actual motto is showing local image into every input tag (Universal)

**Done:**

```
 NSString *strJSInjection = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".%@{  background-image:url(https://s29.postimg.org/qqxoigjbr/Arun_Photo.png); background-position: right top; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; }",[inputNode getAttributeNamed:@"class"]];

        NSString *cssString = strJSInjection; // 1
         NSString *javascriptString = @"var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '%@'; document.head.appendChild(style)"; // 2
        NSString *javascriptWithCSSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:javascriptString, cssString]; // 3
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptWithCSSString]; // 4
```

Comment: Did you know the class name or id of textfield which want to insert image?

Comment: Yes, I do have access of text field,  I tried to inject javascript but still not getting any success . . .

Comment: Please try out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" class="textBox" />
```

Lets assume above is your `HTML textfield` then apply CSS to this to insert image just try below code,

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *cssString = @".textBox{  background-image:url(https://s29.postimg.org/qqxoigjbr/Arun_Photo.png); background-position: right top; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; }"; // 1
    NSString *javascriptString = @"var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '%@'; document.head.appendChild(style)"; // 2
    NSString *javascriptWithCSSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:javascriptString, cssString]; // 3
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptWithCSSString]; // 4
}
```

For *Local Image file* you can try out the below code snippet,

```
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"];
NSString *cssString =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@".textBox{  background-image:url(%@); background-position: right top; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; }",url]; // 1
```

Comment: It will work if you put correct path to your local image file

Comment: Before trying it with objective C, you can just confirm your css and link is working by putting your code here
https://jsfiddle.net/r3ta1e2f/

Comment: Thanks, I've done it, just enlighten me about how to show the local image if possible . . .

Comment: I updated the answer for local file also you can try out this

Comment: Thanks , is it possible to do the same in WKWebView? any idea?